# python / pandas from timetable to timedate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a set of data like this:

```
    Unnamed: 0  0:30  1:00  1:30  2:00  2:30  3:00  3:30  4:00  4:30  ...   \
0   2016-01-01  26.9  26.4  26.9  26.1  26.4  26.7  26.5  25.5  25.4  ...    
1   2016-01-02  26.8  25.9  25.7  26.0  25.2  25.3  25.6  25.0  25.1  ...    
2   2016-01-03  25.6  25.4  25.2  25.5  24.5  24.5  24.9  24.6  24.3  ...    
3   2016-01-04  24.9  24.2  23.7  23.5  23.4  23.4  23.6  23.3  23.7  ...
..         ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ... 
361 2016-12-27  15.6  15.5  15.5  15.7  16.1  16.2  16.3  16.2  16.2  ...    
362 2016-12-28  15.3  15.7  16.3  16.4  16.2  16.1  16.3  16.1  16.2  ...    
363 2016-12-29  15.9  16.3  16.1  16.4  16.4  16.2  16.1  16.1  15.9  ...    
364 2016-12-30  16.2  16.3  16.3  16.3  16.2  16.3  16.3  16.3  16.3  ...    
365 2016-12-31  16.1  16.0  16.2  16.3  16.2  16.2  16.3  16.3  16.3  ...
```

that I would like to rearrange with date+time for each value at each row. something like:

```
0   2016-01-01 0:30 26.9
1   2016-01-01 1:00 26.4
2   2016-01-01 1:30 26.9
3   2016-01-01 2:00 26.1
```

but i haven't a clue how to append the values into a new dataframe without iterating (which is very slow as i have several big data-sets)

i tried something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = data['Unnamed: 0'] + ' ' + data.columns[1:len(data.columns)])
```

but this isn't right - it is the data structure that i don't get i think

ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@A-Za-z's answer was my first thought... but if you wanted the new index values to be timestamps that include the time elements from the columns...

- `set_index` to get dates into index so I can grab all the values easily
- turn columns into time deltas
- turn index into date times
- use `numpy` broadcasting to generate all timestamps
- construct new series with `ravel`d values and timestamps

---

```
d1 = df.set_index('Unnamed: 0')

td = pd.to_timedelta(d1.columns + ':00').values
ts = pd.to_datetime(d1.index).values

pd.Series(
    d1.values.ravel(),
    (ts[:, None] + td).ravel()
)
```

---

Output:

```
2016-01-01 00:30:00    26.9
2016-01-01 01:00:00    26.4
2016-01-01 01:30:00    26.9
2016-01-01 02:00:00    26.1
2016-01-01 02:30:00    26.4
2016-01-01 03:00:00    26.7
2016-01-01 03:30:00    26.5
2016-01-01 04:00:00    25.5
2016-01-01 04:30:00    25.4
2016-01-02 00:30:00    26.8
2016-01-02 01:00:00    25.9
2016-01-02 01:30:00    25.7
2016-01-02 02:00:00    26.0
2016-01-02 02:30:00    25.2
2016-01-02 03:00:00    25.3
2016-01-02 03:30:00    25.6
2016-01-02 04:00:00    25.0
2016-01-02 04:30:00    25.1
2016-01-03 00:30:00    25.6
2016-01-03 01:00:00    25.4
2016-01-03 01:30:00    25.2
2016-01-03 02:00:00    25.5
2016-01-03 02:30:00    24.5
2016-01-03 03:00:00    24.5
2016-01-03 03:30:00    24.9
2016-01-03 04:00:00    24.6
2016-01-03 04:30:00    24.3
2016-01-04 00:30:00    24.9
2016-01-04 01:00:00    24.2
2016-01-04 01:30:00    23.7
                       ... 
2016-12-28 03:30:00    16.3
2016-12-28 04:00:00    16.1
2016-12-28 04:30:00    16.2
2016-12-29 00:30:00    15.9
2016-12-29 01:00:00    16.3
2016-12-29 01:30:00    16.1
2016-12-29 02:00:00    16.4
2016-12-29 02:30:00    16.4
2016-12-29 03:00:00    16.2
2016-12-29 03:30:00    16.1
2016-12-29 04:00:00    16.1
2016-12-29 04:30:00    15.9
2016-12-30 00:30:00    16.2
2016-12-30 01:00:00    16.3
2016-12-30 01:30:00    16.3
2016-12-30 02:00:00    16.3
2016-12-30 02:30:00    16.2
2016-12-30 03:00:00    16.3
2016-12-30 03:30:00    16.3
2016-12-30 04:00:00    16.3
2016-12-30 04:30:00    16.3
2016-12-31 00:30:00    16.1
2016-12-31 01:00:00    16.0
2016-12-31 01:30:00    16.2
2016-12-31 02:00:00    16.3
2016-12-31 02:30:00    16.2
2016-12-31 03:00:00    16.2
2016-12-31 03:30:00    16.3
2016-12-31 04:00:00    16.3
2016-12-31 04:30:00    16.3
Length: 81, dtype: float64
```

Comment: well this works great @piRSquared. however i don't understand the move you've made with the time deltas and then coupling them with the time series. when checked the timedeltas values i got: [ 1800000000000  3600000000000  5400000000000 ..., 82800000000000
 84600000000000              0] - which makes no sense to me.

Comment: @NoamNaveh those are nanoseconds

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas stack() for this

```
df.set_index('Unnamed: 0').stack().reset_index()

    Unnamed: 0  level_1 0
0   2016-01-01  0:30    26.9
1   2016-01-01  1:00    26.4
2   2016-01-01  1:30    26.9
3   2016-01-01  2:00    26.1
4   2016-01-01  2:30    26.4
5   2016-01-01  3:00    26.7
6   2016-01-01  3:30    26.5
7   2016-01-01  4:00    25.5
8   2016-01-01  4:30    25.4
9   2016-01-02  0:30    26.8
10  2016-01-02  1:00    25.9
11  2016-01-02  1:30    25.7
12  2016-01-02  2:00    26.0
13  2016-01-02  2:30    25.2
14  2016-01-02  3:00    25.3
15  2016-01-02  3:30    25.6
```